# How to write data to different databases based on measurement name

Tags: influxdb, graphite, telegraf

I have two databases in Influxdb:

- base1
- base2

And metrics like these:

```
base1.example.allRequests.all.percentiles99 807 1607947555
base2.example.allRequests.all.percentiles99 807 1607947555
```

I have solution with influx.conf where I'm sending data on different ports.

http://localhost:2003 for base1.....

http://localhost:2004 for base2.....

```
[[graphite]]
…
bind-address = ":2003”
database = "base-1”
…

[[graphite]]
…
bind-address = ":2004”
database = "base-2”
…
```

However, I think there is a better solution for this case where data can be sent based on measurement not just using ports. Can someone please help me or suggest how to it?

Comment: I suggest check how the InfluxDB Line Protocol. You can specify there which measurement you would like. You don't need to have separate DBs on separate ports. In on DB you can have > Orgs > Buckets > Measurements.

Comment: @Newskooler
I need different databases for different products at least. Because they can write with another retention policy. 

It's also about performance. The selection will be based on different bases, and not on different tags.

Comment: I think you don't fully undersstand the InfluxDB 2.x model. You have A DB.  Then inside DB you have separate Organization. In each organization you can have multiple bucket. Each bucket in turn can have multiple measurements. Only then (inside the measurement) you have tags. I am not talking about the tags in my previous post. I only say you probably don't need two InfluxDB instances to do what you describe in the post.